# How to ensure data consistency between many microservices?

Tags: microservices

My application comprises of many services. Two of them (service A and service B) share the same MongoDB database, which is deployed on AWS to be one write instance and many read instances. Let say the service A performs an update to a database record X, which triggers a Kafka event to notify about this change, and B is expected to subscribe to that event. When processing the Kafka event, service B needs to query from the database to get the latest values for record X before moving on. However, by the time service B query for that record from a specific read instance, the latest values for X may not be replicated completely to this instance. How can we ensure that the service B will be able to get the latest X when it processes the Kafka event?

I have not come up with any solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical solution in your case is B calling the leader instance (the writer) to get the latest data. This approach comes from the logic that any reader instance can be behind and have no latest data due to issues with replication.

Another approach is to send all needed information for B with the event itself. In this case, B does not need to do any reads, hence replication has no effect.

The last approach could be slightly modified in case if the event can't contain the entirety of data. Include an identifier for the change into the event (id + timestamp as an example). When B reads the data, B may use that information to see if the date read from the db is stale.

Last approach, by itself, does not prevent B from missing data, but B will be aware about if the data is stale. So it may reconnect to another instance and retry.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort if you can't solve it by design, you should delay processing the event until all the conditions for processing are met.

We do that usually using retries topics and mechanism of delaying based on the current retry level.